# Migrating from Rails 2 to Rails 3 problem (nil.any?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, actioncontroller

I've been upgrading my app from Rails 2.3.8 to Rails 3.

After getting all the basic stuff done (configs, routes, and the new AR API, replacing Authlogic with Devise) and getting some mostly static pages to show up fine I get an error in the rest of my site:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.any?
```

This error always appears when I reference `SomeModel` for the first time.
E.g., in my `news#index`:

```
@news_story = NewsStory.new # gets called from before_filter
```

The full stack trace is below.
The trace seems to indicate that the model in my `app/models/news_story.rb` does not get loaded.

I've been struggling with this the whole day. Does anyone have an idea of what is going on?

```
# stack trace:
activesupport (3.0.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:497:in `load_missing_constant'
activesupport (3.0.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `block in const_missing'
activesupport (3.0.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `each'
activesupport (3.0.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `const_missing'
app/controllers/news_controller.rb:82:in `new_post'
activesupport (3.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:451:in `_run__810448074__process_action__85542351__callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:409:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
...
```

Controller action:

```
class NewsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :new_post_from_params, :only => :create
  before_filter :new_post, :only => [:index, :new]
  before_filter :find_post, :except => [:index, :create, :new]
  filter_access_to :all, :attribute_check => true

  def index
    @user = current_user
    @news = NewsStory.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml { render :xml => @user.news }
    end
  end
  #...
  private

  def new_post_from_params
    @news_story = NewsStory.new(params[:news_story])
  end

  def new_post
    @news_story = NewsStory.new
  end

  def find_post
    @news_story = NewsStory.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

#### Additional info:

- [app/models/news_story.rb](http://gist.github.com/618725)
- [Gemfile](http://gist.github.com/618722)
- [config/application.rb](http://gist.github.com/618679)
- Ruby version:

  ```
  ~ $ ruby -v
  ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [i686-linux]
  ```
- Creating news story from console:

  ```
  irb(main):001:0> NewsStory.new
  => #<NewsStory id: nil, title: nil, body: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
  ```

Comment: Can you please post your controller action, specifically around line 82?

Comment: done. line 82 is `@news_story = NewsStory.new` in `#new_post`

Comment: It shouldn't matter for this error, but why does the index action need a new NewsStory?

Comment: Oh, if you are an admin you can post a new story from the same screen (for convenience)

Comment: That doesn't look like an error you would get if the class could not be found. Does the initializer for NewsStory have anything in it?

Comment: Also, can you start the console and run NewsStory.new without having it blow up?

Comment: I've updated my post with news_story.rb and console output (looks like I can build a story from the console just fine). I get the same exception with all the models in my app.

Comment: Well, I gave you a +1 for the question, because it's clearly asked. I hope that you can find an equally good answer for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was that some parent_* methods I defined in my application controller had a name collision with the new ActionController methods, which did not happen in Rails 3.

Took me forever to figure out, dammit